# Tableau ERROR: Error Executing Query

Tags: tableau-api

I have several joined data sources and my chart will load properly, however when I attempt to edit a filter and change the radio button from "Custom value list" to "Select from list", it loads for ~15 minutes, then gives the following error:

> ERROR: Error executing query. Total time 900.0 seconds. QUERY
>   [GROUPBY] [QUERY_TIMEOUT] QUERY [PROJECTION] [PROCESSING] QUERY [JOIN]
>   [QUERY_TIMEOUT] QUERY [PROJECTION] [PROCESSING] QUERY [SELECTION] [PR
>   java.sql.SQLException: Error executing query. Total time 900.0
>   seconds. QUERY [GROUPBY] [QUERY_TIMEOUT] QUERY [PROJECTION]
>   [PROCESSING] QUERY [JOIN] [QUERY_TIMEOUT] QUERY [PROJECTION]
>   [PROCESSING] QUERY [SELECTION] [PR; Error while executing the query

The query was as follows:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (CAST("fv_dr_status_lob"."tracking_date" AS DATE) >= "t0"."__measure__0") THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Calculation_551972462897504258"
FROM "data_source"."fv_dr_status_lob" "fv_dr_status_lob"
  CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(CAST("fv_dr_status_lob"."tracking_date" AS DATE)) AS "__measure__0"
  FROM "data_source"."dv_iipm_lob_denormalized_join" "dv_iipm_lob_denormalized_join"
    INNER JOIN "data_source"."fv_asra_findings_iipm" "fv_asra_findings_iipm" ON ("dv_iipm_lob_denormalized_join"."appcoordinatorempnumber_0" = "fv_asra_findings_iipm"."appcoordinatorempnumber_0")
    INNER JOIN "data_source"."fv_dr_status_lob" "fv_dr_status_lob" ON ("dv_iipm_lob_denormalized_join"."appcoordinatorempnumber_0" = "fv_dr_status_lob"."appcoordinatorempnumber_0")
    INNER JOIN "data_source"."fv_unix_compliancy_lob" "fv_unix_compliancy_lob" ON ("dv_iipm_lob_denormalized_join"."appcoordinatorempnumber_0" = "fv_unix_compliancy_lob"."appcoordinatorempnumber_0")
    INNER JOIN "data_source"."fv_windows_compliancy_lob" "fv_windows_compliancy_lob" ON ("dv_iipm_lob_denormalized_join"."appcoordinatorempnumber_0" = "fv_windows_compliancy_lob"."appcoordinatorempnumber_0")
  HAVING (COUNT(1) > 0)
) "t0"
GROUP BY 1
```

My assumption is that perhaps the filter is trying to be applied to a field that is not present in all of the data sources.  Could this be the case?  Otherwise, what else might be causing this error?

Comment: Are you using an extract or live connection?

Comment: I'm using an extract

Comment: Just a hunch,but try checking the option to assume referential integrity for your data source